# SEO titles/descriptions for tags and archive pages

Tags: tags, seo, layout, archives

I have a blog setup with a Categories, Archive and Tags.

In my _layout template I've been using the following to pull in SEO titles from fields, or Page/Category Titles is that's not been defined.

```
{% if entry is defined %}
    {% set seoTitle = entry.seoTitle %}
    {% set seoDescription = entry.seoDescription %}
    {% set seoImage = entry.seoImage %}
    {% set seoType = entry.seoType %}
    {% set title = entry.title %}
    {% set url = entry.url %}
{% endif %}


{% if category is defined %}
    {% set seoTitle = category.title %}
    {% set seoDescription = category.title %}
    {% set seoImage = category.seoImage %}
    {% set seoType = category.seoType %}
    {% set title = category.title %}
    {% set url = category.url %}
{% endif %}

<title>{{ siteName }} - {% if seoTitle is not empty %}{{ seoTitle }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{% if seoDescription is defined %}{{ seoDescription }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}"/>
{% if url is defined %}<link rel="home" href="{{ url }}" />{% endif %}
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
{% if url is defined %}<meta property="og:url" content="{{ url }}" />{% endif %}
<meta property="og:title" content="{% if seoTitle is not empty %}{{ seoTitle }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{% if seoDescription is defined %}{{ seoDescription }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}" />
{% if seoImage is defined %}
    {% for image in seoImage %}
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ image.getUrl()}}" />
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How should I approach this for the archive and tag pages as simply doing something like the below doesn't work?

```
{% if tag is defined %}
{% set seoTitle = tag.title %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: You could write a conditional based on the url segment if you have the tag or category visible in the url. Something like: `{% if craft.request.getSegment(x) == tag.slug %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better approach in my opinion is to declare the variables in the corresponding templates rather than in the `_layout` template

#### Layout.twig

```
{% if seoTitle is not defined or seoTitle is empty %}
    {% set seoTitle = config.seoTitle %} <-- fallback if nothing is defined
{% endif %}
<title>{{ siteName }} - {{ seoTitle }}</title>
```

#### _entry.twig

```
{% extends 'layout' %}
{% set seoTitle = entry.seoTitle %}
```

#### _category.twig

```
{% extends 'layout' %}
{% set seoTitle = category.seoTitle %}
```

#### _someOtherTemplates.twig

```
{% extends 'layout' %}
{% set seoTitle = 'Some hard coded strings....' %}
```

and so on. That way you can define `seoTags` based on custom properties as well otherwise it would be difficult to determinate tags on dynamic template routes without an entry or a category